# Got NoClassDefFoundError when invoking Axis2 webservice deployed with maven in weblogic

Tags: maven, weblogic, apache-axis

I'm trying to deploy axis2 webservices in weblogic server using maven. The project has maven modules and one of that is a war that i have defined the axis servlet in. The wsdl was there, so i used wsdl2code plugin to generate the xmlbean and schema and put that in a jar module. Structure is as below.

```
--lv-ear (ear with dependency on war)
|
--lv-ws
  |
  --lv-ws-ccid (jar module with skeleton and xmlbeans)
  |
  --lv-ws-ecs (jar module with skeleton and xmlbeans)
|
--lv-ws-web (war module with dep on jar modules)
  |
  --WEB-INF
    |
    --conf/axis2.xml
    --services/ccid/services.xml
```

I built and deployed the ear to weblogic domain. The war was deployed successfully as part of ear and services were deployed. I am able to access wsdl files. When I tried to call the service, i got the below **ClassNotFoundException** for a schema file.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.s2104B1E6E09A2A85656B3E630BA151C1.TypeSystemHolder
```

I saw that the random string in that path differed fo me. So I tried to call again and got below **NoClassDefFoundError**, which persists even after I tried with different approaches.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.lv.ws.ccid.xmlbean.InputDocument
    at com.lv.ws.ccid.xmlbean.InputDocument$Factory.parse(InputDocument.java:463)
    at com.lv.ws.ccid.CcidMessageReceiverInOut.fromOM(CcidMessageReceiverInOut.java:332)
    at com.lv.ws.ccid.CcidMessageReceiverInOut.invokeBusinessLogic(CcidMessageReceiverInOut.java:46)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:144)
```

I searched for this and found something that told to configure app server for axis2 based on http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html . When I tried it I got below error.

```
weblogic.xml.stax.XmlStreamInputFactory can not be cast to javax.xml.stream.XmlInputFactory
```

After discarding that configuration, I did some other possible deployments by having the webservice skeleton and xmlbean files in an aar and put the aar inside *WEB-INF/services*. I also tried putting *Class-Path* entry in MANIFEST.MF in ear / war for the jar files, to no avail. Still I got the same **NoClassDefFoundError**. Can you please give me suggestions on fixing that?

Comment: The first `ClassNotFoundException` is related to how xml bean classes are auto-generated. A full clean build usually will get you past that. Other than that it's hard to tell what you're asking because you've listed so many errors.

Comment: Sorry for that listing. I just wanted to mention what I encountered. The issue is the NoClassDefFoundError. I'll edit to emphasize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it now. This was due to my lack of experience with Axis. Issue was that, I had the generated schema and xmlbean files moved to src folder and then just tried to use normal jar function and dependency to deploy.

Now, I removed them from src folder and use wsdl2code and axis2-aar plugins to generate the xmlbean and schema files dynamically and then package them in aar. Then I deployed the aar to webapp and it worked fine. I have listed the plugin configuration inside <build> below.

```
 <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>ccid-ws</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <packageName>com.lv.ws.ccid</packageName>
                <wsdlFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/ccid.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                <databindingName>xmlbeans</databindingName>
                <syncMode>sync</syncMode>
                <unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
                <namespaceToPackages>https://mdm.com/portal/ws/services/ccid=com.lv.ws.ccid.xmlbean</namespaceToPackages>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>                              <generateServerSide>false</generateServerSide> 
                <generateServicesXml>true</generateServicesXml>
                <skipWSDL>true</skipWSDL>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>  
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-aar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <aarName>ccid</aarName>
                <includeDependencies>false</includeDependencies>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/aar</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```